# Why does my DataGridView flicker (columns shrink and return to their original size)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Datagridview that receives external data and I added 3 columns independent of the external data

My datagridview refreshes every 3 seconds and during the refresh the table flickers (that is to say that the cells shrink and return to their original size) and also the content of the 3 independent columns (those added) disappear and reappear.

I have this problem with this added code (see below which corresponds to an added column), if I delete this piece of code the problem disappears:

```
var id = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
var nickNameTask = Task.Run<string>(async() => await this.GetTraderName(id));
nickNameTask.Wait();
string nickName = nickNameTask.Result;
row.Cells[1].Value =nickName;
```

Do you know where the problem can come from and how to correct it?

Here is the code:

```
private void dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lstUID = this.ReplaceDownTheLine(this.txtUIDs.Text.Trim());
    Dictionary<string, bool> lstUIDColor = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    for (int index = 0; index < lstUID.Count; ++index)
        lstUIDColor.Add(lstUID[index], index % 2 == 0);
    this.dtgvPositions.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        foreach (string str in lstUID)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (IEnumerable)this.dtgvPositions.Rows)
            {
                string key  = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                Decimal num = 0M;
                Decimal num1 = 0M;
                Decimal num2 = 0M;
                Decimal num3 = 0M;
                try
                {
                    num  = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                    num1 = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                    num2 = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                    num3 = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());


                    var id = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    var nickNameTask = Task.Run<string>(async() => await this.GetTraderName(id));
                    nickNameTask.Wait();
                    string nickName = nickNameTask.Result;
                    row.Cells[1].Value =nickName;

                    bool flag;
                    lstUIDColor.TryGetValue(key, out flag);
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(24, 26, 32);
                    row.Cells[1].Selected = false; 
                    row.Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = flag ? Color.LightSkyBlue : Color.LightPink; 
                    row.Cells[2].Value = num1 >= 0M ? "Long" : "Short";
                    row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = num1 >= 0M ? Color.FromArgb(22, 181, 93) : Color.FromArgb(194, 52, 54);
                    row.Cells[6].Value = (num1 * num2) / num3; 
                    row.Cells[9].Style.ForeColor = num >= 0M ? Color.FromArgb(22, 181, 93) : Color.FromArgb(194, 52, 54);
                    row.Cells[10].Style.ForeColor = num >= 0M ? Color.FromArgb(22, 181, 93) : Color.FromArgb(194, 52, 54);
                }
                catch
                {
                }

            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: In dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete, did you try to put *dtgvPositions.SuspendLayout()* at beginning of the procedure and *dtgvPositions.ResumeLayout()* at end ?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but it's still the same

Comment: I am not surprised. Most of the time, it doesn't often work. At beginning of dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete, do *Control saveparent = dtgvPositions.Parent ; dtgvPositions.Parent = null;* and at end *dtgvPositions.Parent  = saveparent* ;

Comment: No, it didn't work. 
But I just found out that if my mouse hovers over my Winform the independent cells (which are not linked to the external source) blink, and if my mouse doesn't hover over my Winform then it doesn't blink anymore (so it works fine)... it's weird ;)

Comment: Do you have any mousehover event in your DGV (for example, to display hints) ?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check this please?

Comment: I was just wandering if *you* have defined in the form or code some  dtgvPositions_MouseOver() event.

Comment: After verification no I have no mousehover event

Comment: According to your description, it seems to be caused by thread blocking. Try using asynchronous operations. Like this: private async void dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete

Comment: Thank you, I tried private async void but I still have the same problem

Comment: A workaround would be to to use a DataTable as binding source for your DGV. At beginning of *dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete*, create a new DataTable. Instead of filling the DGV rows, add and fill DataTalbe rows. At end of the procedure, use that new DataTable as binding source, replacing the old one.